# Http status 500 - NullPointerException: while processing huge data in Excel File

Tags: excel, jsp

i'm working with struts 1.3 project with jsp file that works as to extract the Excel file, but i get error when the data in excel file is huge i.e more than 10000.

here is the code snippet with error :

Below is the error :

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /pages/console/popUpExcell.jsp at 
line 14
 ________________________________________
type Exception report
message An exception occurred processing JSP page /pages/console/popUpExcell.jsp at line 14
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling request.
exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException:Feb 25, 2014 6:20:33 PM    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/project] threw exception   [An exception occurred processing JSP page /pages/console/popUpExcell.jsp at line 15     11: 
 12: String cadena = request.getParameter("cadena");
 13: System.out.println("cd="+cadena);
 14: cadena=cadena.replaceAll("<INPUT type=checkbox name=validar>","");
 15: response.containsHeader("application/vnd.ms-excel");
 16: response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
 17: response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file1.xls");
 Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
 root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jsp.pages.console.popUpExcell_jsp._jspService(popUpExcell_jsp.java:84)
```

Here error occurs when there is huge data i.e. more than 10000. but if the data is less than it     works properly.

i.e when list of data is more **String cadena = request.getParameter("cadena") gives me null**
    and when list of data is less then works properly

file **popUpExcell.jsp**

```
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE>
  </TITLE>
  </HEAD>

   <body bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">      
   <% 
    String cadena = request.getParameter("cadena");
   System.out.println("cd="+cadena);
   cadena=cadena.replaceAll("<INPUT type=checkbox name=validar>","");
 response.containsHeader("application/vnd.ms-excel");
 response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
 response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file1.xls");
  %>
 <table  border="1" bordercolorLight="blue" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" style="border:      solid #000000; background color:#ffffff;table-layout:auto;">
<tr bgcolor="#333399">
<td align="center"class="Text222" width="20"     >&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"  width="70" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu"/></td>
<td align="center" width="90" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu.type"/></td>
<td align="center" width="200" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu.location"/></td>
<td align="center" width="200" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu.detail"/></td>
<td align="center" width="170" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu.customer"/></td>
<td align="center" width="200" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu.zipcode"/></td>
<td align="center" width="180" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu.destination"/></td>
<td align="center" width="110" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu.status"/></td>
<td align="center" width="90" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu.Logdate"/></td>
<td align="center" width="170" class="blanco"><bean:message key="menu.vendor"/></td>

</tr>
     </table>
   <%=cadena %>
```

i'm using a javascript function i.e on click of a button export excel appers :

```
 function fnCopyReportTable()
        {
            cadena=frames.frameId.document.all.listTable.innerHTML;
            alert(cadena);  // here it displays HTML DOM
            document.form1.cadena.value=cadena;
            form1.action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/pages/file/popUpExcell.jsp";
            form1.submit();
        }
```

Here the list contains export to excel sheet. But this above problem i face when `<%=cadena%>` contains large data.
cadena refers **HTML DOM** in it.
want to solve the error when there is large data in it.

Comment: Where is this: `popUpExcell_jsp.java:84`

Comment: I doubt is it working with less data !! Its not about the amount of data.

Comment: There is a maximum size for parameters submitted to the web server.  Would I be right in thinking that you are using a GET request?  This would explain the small size of your parameter.  This is related to HTTP parameter sizes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: its working file when data is around 500 but gives me above error when data is large i.e 7000 (ex.when i need export file for a particular status "Linked" contains less data around 300. and it works fine ) but when i want to export file for status "Delivered" contains more data around 8000 it gives me above error.

Comment: @ beny23: hi. i checked it by request.getMethod() (which prints POST on console screen);

Comment: i have edited by question: when i click on a button export excel appers and here cadena=frames.frameId.document.all.listTable.innerHTML

Comment: now i am setting   maxPostSize="0" (unlimited size)  or set size maxPostSize="67589953"  in the Tomcat's server.xml Connector Component. No Error occurs. But here Excel Sheet Stops at the end (i think its due to Excel Sheet conatins large data).

Comment: @Responsible for -ve mark: May i kno the reason why this question being negatively marked. As i did put in effort for conveying the question to an extent. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On load of JSP, the request object cannot find the parameter cadena.

So,

```
String cadena = request.getParameter("cadena");
```

gives you null.

Wrap the content over saying that,

`if(request.getMethod().equals("POST")` or `if(request.getMethod().equals("GET")`

so that, JSP will execute the content only if the page is called.